# Load controls to SSTab tabs other than 0 at run time

Tags: vb6

I have an SSTab object that I am adding both tabs, and controls to at run time.
I've only been able to get runtime controls to appear in Tab0 at run time.
(In other cases, where the new controls are part of an array that was already in, say Tab3 at design time, I can add extra controls there - provided the tab in question is the active tab).
I'd thought initially that I needed to set the container of my new controls to the relevant tab of the SSTab. I can't actually see how to do this, and some reading around suggests that perhaps the SSTab control doesn't work quite how one might expect?

Answer (score 0):

So, being unable to find out if this was possible with SSTab, I ended up doing something else.

Using a TabStrip from Microsoft Common Controls 6.0, combined with frames that were created dynamically at runtime when a new tab was added, and using these frames as containers for controls, I was able to acheive what I wanted - witha fair bit more code that I was hoping for.

(I won't be accepting this answer, in the hope that someone can answer the original question about the SSTab control)